# Nginx + PHP + FTP - user permission issue

Tags: ubuntu, php, nginx

I have a wordpress copy installed on /home/username/public_html/site, and now the problem is :

1. Nginx running PHP with "www-data" identity
2. The site folder owner and group are "username", not "www-data"
3. So wordpress had no permission to create folder
4. I changed owner and group of "site" to "www-data", wordpress is working ok
5. But ftp can't create a folder - ftp is login as username/pass

Is it possible to have a /home/username/public_html/site, and both working on PHP side and ftp side. Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I found how to solve it, not a elegant way :

1. change "user" primary group to "www-data"
2. change /etc/vsftpd.conf and ~./bashrc, add local_mask = 002 to the first one, and umask = 002 to the last one

Now when I uploaded a file, by default it had permission rw-rw-r-, if its a folder rwxrwxr--, the owner is "user", and group is "www-data", and PHP is running with identity "www-data", so it can delete all files and folders uploaded from ftp.

Answer (score 0):

Changing user primary group to "www=data" could work, but may be insecure in some cases.
Adding umask option could be much more likely unsecure.

I would recommend little more complicated aproach, which may have some performance effect, but could be setup more securily: http://themesforge.com/performance/configuring-nginx-php5-fpm-and-user-permissions/